# Can I use multiple chaincode using a single Bluemix blockchain service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I'm new to `IBM Bluemix Blockchain` service. I wonder if I can create multiple chain code. This is because I got the following error.

```
! looks like an error loading the chaincode or network, app will fail
{ name: 'register() error',
code: 401,
details: { Error: 'rpc error: code = 13 desc = \'server closed the stream without sending trailers\'' } }
```

**Here is what I did:**

1. Create a blockchain serivce, and nameded as *'blockchain'*.
2. Run [cp-web example](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/cp-web) => Success
3. Run [marbles demo](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles) using **existing blockchain service** (*'blockchain'*). => Gives me the above error
4. Newly create a blockchain service, names as '*mbblochchain*'
5. Repush marbles demo with new service name => Success

So I wonder if I can put multiple chaincode into peer's network or not. It is likely I may be misunderstanding how it works or should behave.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can deploy multiple chaincodes on the same network. The issue you are having is because each app is registering users differently.

Currently only 1 username (aka enrollID) can be registered against 1 peer. If you try to register the same username against two peers, the 2nd registration will fail.  This is what is happening to you.

The Bluemix blockchain service is returning two type1 usernames (type1 is the type of enrollID these apps want to use).

- cp-web will register the first and second enrollID against peer vp1
- marbles will register the first enrollID against vp1 and the 2nd enrollID against vp2

Therefore when you ran marbles after cp-web it tried to register the 2nd enrollID against vp2 when it had already been registered with vp1.  Thus giving  you an error.

Comment: Thanks. This explains the error message I saw. I'll try not to register the same usernames somehow to see if I can register two chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can deploy multiple chaincode apps to a single instance of the Bluemix Blockchain service and more broadly speaking multiple chaincode apps to a single peer network.

Were you deploying the web apps directly using "cf push" and trying to bind to existing Blockchain service instance or where you trying to use the "deploy to Bluemix" functionality?

Comment: I had a similar issue using the "deploy to bluemix" button. Was able to redeploy successfully. There may be a timeout affecting some.